# How to align buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can buttons be aligned in android so that they have proper spacing above, below, and  between buttons?

Current code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include 
     android:id="@+id/ActionBackupBar"
     layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" 
    />
```

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnSelectLocation"
      style="@style/ButtonText"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
      android:text="@string/activitySelectMyLocationButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:text="@string/activitySelectSearchLocationButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Fill_parent is deprecated, use match_parent.
2. Using sp for margins doesn't make sense. Use dp instead.
3. What do you want to achieve? How do you want to align these buttons? As in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Change for RelativeLayout and after try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSelectLocation"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="text1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSelectLocation"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="test2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.
Then you can easily align the buttons.

Hope this can help you.